# Running Ubuntu on Toshiba L630

Tags: linux, ubuntu, toshiba-laptop

I was suffering with the following error while trying to install Ubuntu onto my Toshiba L630:

```
kernel_thread_helper+0x0 0x10
```

I bypassed the error and managed to install the OS by going into the Installation setup menu (by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> while booting from my Ubuntu Installation CD) and assigning `acpi = off`. I believe this fixes the problem because it stops the laptop doing checks that aren't compatible with the software.

However, now that I have Ubuntu installed, I cannot run the bloody thing because I have no way of choosing `acpi=off` before booting Ubuntu.

I guess this is a pretty broad question but I'm going to ask it anyways. Has anyone managed to find a version of Linux that works on an L630 without any errors? If not, Is there a way to choose `acpi=off` before booting? Maybe by adding a line to the grub?

Also, does anybody think I'm wasting my time? I read somewhere that Toshiba laptops don't work well with Linux. So if there isn't a fix for this I would appreciate being alerted about this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to append the acpi=off to the end of the kernel line in grub.conf.

It'd look something like this:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i586 ro rhgb quiet acpi=off
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Fedora 12 on my Toshiba L630. But my Fedora uses the PAE kernel.

I don't understand to why much of Linux distro can't installed on Toshiba laptop (including openSUSE, the distro which awarded as the best distro for laptops).

My friend with a Toshiba L640 has no problem installing any distro on his laptop. But in my experience I have successfully installed Vector Linux SOHO 6.0 on my L630 without any problem (except on fs check).